# Starting tag <td> not closed?

Tags: java, jsp, struct

Please have a look at the below code:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" id="id1">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%" nowrap>
            <Label class="someClass"> Testing </Label>
        </td>
        //Error complaining at below line
        <td width="30%" class="someClass" nowrap>
            <html-el:text styleClass="Test" property="someProperty" size="30" maxlength="10"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For the first **td** I've closed it but at the second **td** it's complaining **IWAK0061E Start tag() not closed.**

May I know what's wrong?

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Don't worry about that, in the actual code it will not be there. That line I added here just to show where the error is

Comment: All your tags are balanced in the shared html. Maybe something is wrong in html-el

Comment: What's the **it** that's complaining? Where are you getting this error message? Is there any further information (e.g., how do you know which line it's talking about)?

Comment: @chrylis: I'm doing development using **Application Developer 5.1.2** which can tell you there are errors on your code by having a red line underneath your code.

Comment: if you delete `<html-el:text ..` part, is the error still appear?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you use such weird html syntax ,however I would use:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" id="id1">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%">
            <Label class="some class"> Testing </Label>
        </td>
        <td width="30%" class="some class">
            <textarea property="some property" maxlength="10" class="some class"></textarea> // all visual stuff is used with class tag
            <input property="some property" maxlength="10" class="some class"> // or input with one line field
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also, nowrap attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: which one _weird_ refers to?

Comment: oh that tag provided by [struts framework](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/struts2/info) I guess